# Using NetBeans for creating .class files for Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to Java and now learning how to use NetBeans as IDE.
Say, I have the following code in an existing .java file without any .class file.

```
class Car
{
   private int num;
   private double gas;

   public Car()
   {
      num = 0;
      gas = 0.0;
      System.out.println("Car created");
   }
   public Car(int n, double g)
   {
      this();
      num = n;
      gas = g;
      System.out.println("Car number as" + num + "Gas volume as" + gas + "。");
   }
   public void show()
   {
      System.out.println("Car number is" + num + ".");
      System.out.println("Gas volume is" + gas + ".");
   }
}

class Sample6
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Car car1 = new Car();
      car1.show();

      Car car2 = new Car(1234, 25.0);
      car2.show();
   }
}
```

What should I do such that once I copy the above code into the NetBeans environment, NetBeans will automatically create the necessary .class files for me (in this case, car.class and sample6.class)?
Thanks.

Comment: Please do some study first

Comment: Maybe I should make myself more clear.  I have tried to copy the code into the IDE environment and clicked Run >>> Run File but the .class files simply don't appear.  Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Check netbeans output window, it has some errors so your class didn't generate

Comment: @Plaka - Once you save the .java file (assuming *build automatically* is enabled), there must be a *bin* folder generated in the same project where your class files will be generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Java class file contain only one class in a file.
2. Package maintain the class as container
3. NetBeans has many menu , there somewhere you will find **build** project , you need a project too

Edit :

Using java console , complie

```
javac file.java 
// run 
java file
```

[NetBeans quick start](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html)